# Create Map sample that clicks into the actual map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to build something that prevents users from clicking on the interactive aspects of the map until they click the map initially like shown when you google search a place like the Toronto Eaten Centre.

I did a visual mock to better explain: [image: Example picture to demonstrate of my question]

I am using google maps and I am not able to get a div to float over the google maps (which was my first attempt at creating this by just having a div float over that when clicked on would disappear and the map would resize via javascript). Google does this well when you search for a location example found [here](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=eaton+centre).

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/w8s2f6bq/) trying to float a div over top so that i could use it to click into the actual map.

Below is the css of the floating div that will not show above the map even with absolute position and z-indexes

```
.map-floater {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
height: 280px;
width: 100%;
background: #555;
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup isn't right, put the overlay in same container as the map

```
   <div class = "map-holder"> 
       <div class = "map-floater"> </div>
       <iframe src="path/to/map" width= "100%" height = "380px" frameborder="0"/>
    </div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w8s2f6bq/13/)**</kbd>

Comment: Oh dear! Can't believe I made a mistake like that. Thank you!